# Python / Service: AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'json'

Tags: python, json, windows, python-2.7

although inside my development IDE (Python 2.7 in Eclipse / Windows7) my code works, I am encountering a strange error when running it as compiled exe (py2exe) as a Service-Account on a Windows Server (2008 R2):
The error is "AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'json'" and appears immediately after starting the service, which also ends the service, too (starting is just "tried", then program stops).

It appears in this code piece, where i call req.json() (here already with debug-addons):

```
req = self.connect2JIRA_get(jira_url)
print "DEBUG1:", req
print type(req)           
json_data = req.json()  <---     
print "DEBUG2:", json_data
print type(json_data)
```

Debug-Output of this part is:

```
DEBUG1: <Response [200]>
<class 'requests.models.Response'>
DEBUG2: {u'issues': [{u'key': u'TSD-48', u'fields': {u'customfield_10701': {u'self': u'https://server.url/is/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10504', u'id': u'10504', u'value': u'Mittel'}, u'customfield_10700': {u'self': ... .... ... ... (a lot of json data here) ... }
<type 'dict'>
```

Do you have any idea, how I could work around that?
It seems that the compiled code on the other platform behaves differently than the version in my IDE,
maybe I have to write "cleaner", better protected code in that situation or something like that?

Any hints how to find a solution?
Thanks for any help!

---

Update added:
The method basically makes a http request returning an object with the json-data, here it is:

```
def connect2JIRA_get(self, jira_url):
    proxies = settings['proxyserver']
    username = settings['jira_username']
    password = "..."


    req = requests.get(jira_url, 
                 auth=(username, password),
                 proxies=proxies)

    return req
```

Comment: Please show the complete error traceback.

Comment: `self.connect2JIRA_get(jira_url)` returns a boolean in that case. What does the `self.connect2JIRA_get()` method **do**?

Comment: I updated the details about the method above for you...

Comment: The 'traceback' unfortunately is just what the Service reported back, it looks like that:

"The following information was included with the event:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "win32serviceutil.pyo", line 835, in SvcRun
  File "w32AccessCdSrv.pyo", line 48, in SvcDoRun
  File "w32AccessCdSrv.pyo", line 25, in main
  File "w32AccessCd.pyo", line 99, in __init__
  File "w32AccessCd.pyo", line 121, in mainloop
  File "w32AccessCd.pyo", line 317, in pollAutoChangesJIRA
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'json'"


(Line 317 is the marked line in the description above.)